# Convert SVG to image with multiple fonts

Tags: fonts, svg, file-conversion, python

I have an SVG with a custom font defined in the defs section.
When I load it up in Safari everything's fine. Unfortunately, when I try to convert
it, with Python and ImageMagick for example, to a png the information about the
font gets lost.

I'd like to know, if it is possible (and if yes how :D) to convert that image and retain the font in the resulting image... preferably using python.

For example:
Imagine you have an SVG that describes a musical sheet and a special font is used for the notes. So there is a defs section, which describes different font-families for different purposes.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="productSvg" class="playbackCanvas" style="width: 582px; height: 757px;" viewBox="0 0 13285.3 17280">
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
      @font-face {
      font-family: 'MyFont';
      src: url('MyFont-Normal.otf');
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Helvetica';
      ...
    }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <text font-size="95" font-family="Helvetica" x="2" y="2" id="abc" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 0;">x</text>
  <text font-size="120" font-family="MyFont" x="6035" y="2681" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 0;">4 fr</text>
...
```

No problem in a browser. At least in Safari. It did not work as well in Chrome in my tests.

Anyways, I found a way to convert the SVG with a custom font using ImageMagick.

```
convert -font "MyFont-Normal" example.svg example.png
```

Unfortunately, I can't pass multiple fonts as Arguments. Therefore, the text with the Helvetica font-family will also have the special font.

Comment: What do you mean "retain the font in the resulting image"? You mean like get an actual font file from it?

Comment: Ah come on. The downvote wasn't necessary right? I mean... it's a good question.

Comment: PNG images are raster images which can't contain any font information.  Its not possible.

Comment: Well I don't care, if any font information is in the image or not. What I want is to capture what is seen in the SVG as an image. So a smart way to create an image using multiple fonts.

Comment: So just rasterize the SVG.  Almost any vector image editing software can output raster images.  Illustrator, Inkscape, CorelDraw

Comment: Yaa... but I'd like to automate the process und do it from python or commandline. I don't want to manually edit the SVG.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? What resources did you look at? GraphidDesign.StackExchange isn't for programming questions though...

Comment: I think asking this on StackOverflow might get you an answer. In my opinion, this has nothing to do with Graphic Design.

Comment: Hm. Too bad. My research led me here time and time again. That's why I  posted my question here.

Comment: @Nimi - but you wouldn't have "manually edit" the SVG. Opening the image and simply exporting a raster image is all that's necessary. I suppose you could write a script to automate it. It's possible to run Inkscape commands via the command line, more info [here](https://inkscape.org/sk/doc/inkscape-man.html)

Comment: Ok... I was about to continue the conversation, but I think I found the solution I was searching for using inkscape. Thx for the help.

Comment: Hey @Nimi, could you at least add the answer here for any passers-by that have the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is for @PieBie. So this is how I solved the problem. As indicated in the comments, it is possible to call inkscape from the [command line](https://inkscape.org/sk/doc/inkscape-man.html) and
the command can also be called from python. The following steps were necessary to make it work on my machine.

- Install inkscape
- If the svg includes custom fonts make sure that inkscape has access to them. I'm on mac so I had to install my custom fonts to /Library/Fonts
- Use the -e option to export your image

In my case the command looked like this:

```
inkscape /path/to/svg -e ~/blub.png -w 1000 -h 1300
```

I added the -w and -h options, because my png turned out to be huge without the constraints.

In python it might look something like the following

```
import subprocess

#Some other code that creates the SVG or scrapes it from the internet might be here

subprocess.Popen(["inkscape", "/path/to/svg", "-e", "~/blub.png", "-w", "1000", "-h", "1300"])
```